# python why does max(max(float_2d_array)) give wrong answer?

Tags: python, matrix, floating-point, max

for example:

```
a = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 [0.0, 0.0, 1.2852976787772832, 0.7965388321000092, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.409872844109646, 0.17506688391255013, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
print max(max(a))
print max(a)
```

The result is:

> 1.28529767878
>
> [0.0, 0.0, 1.2852976787772832, 0.7965388321000092, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

This is clearly wrong, the max value should be 6.409872844109646.

```
b = []
for i in a:
    b.extend(i)
print max(b)
```

> 6.40987284411

This is python 2.7, Cpython.

Thank you very much.

Comment: why are you expecting 6.409872844109646? .... 1.2852976787772832 looks like the max to me

Comment: You can get the right answer with numpy : `print numpy.max(a)`

Comment: Your expectation from `max(a)` is not right. It is not going to give you the list which has the maximum number.

Comment: @yeniv `max(max(a, key=max))` would do it.

Comment: Or `max(map(max, a))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lists are sorted element-wise. Since the index of `1.2852976787772832` is one place ahead of that of `6.409872844109646` in the candidate sublists, the list containing the former gets picked as the maximum.

In the same index in the second list, we have a `0` and `1.2852976787772832` is clearly greater than 0:

```
[0.0, 0.0, 1.2852976787772832, 0.7965388321000092, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.409872844109646, 0.17506688391255013, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
#           ^ here's your tie-breaker
```

In fact, the next index containing `6.4...` is never checked.

I'm not sure how you expect the maximum sublist to be selected: sublist with maximum sum, sublist containing maximum number? You'll have to code the behavior you want if the default behavior does not cut it.

Comment: maybe the mechanic becomes more obvious when you compare lists of numbers with strings which -- for illustration purposes -- can be considered lists of characters. Alphabetically, "aba" comes after "aac". Same is true for "010" which is sorted behind "002".

Comment: Got it! Thanks, Moses!

Answer (score 1):

Moses already explained why you got the wrong result: first element greater than the other "wins" when comparing lists.

To get the maximum value you have to *flatten* your list:

```
print(max(x for l in a for x in l))
```

Comment: to be honest I rarely _had_ to use `key` with `max`. It's only interesting when you need a data _related_ to the max, but not the value itself.